# Db2 Trigger to Insert/Update Record into Different Table

Tags: triggers, db2

I am trying to create a db2 trigger with the following functionality ...

When a record is inserted / updated into Table1, insert / update that same record into Table2. The catch is, Table1 has 11 columns, and Table2 has 5 columns. The 5 columns in Table2 are the exact same as 5 of the columns in Table1, however, since Table1 has an additional 6 columns, how will the Trigger know which 5 of the 11 specific columns I would like to Insert / Update into Table2?

For example:

Table1

MasterID
SubMasterID
Price
Location
Type
Status
Contact First Name
Contact Last Name
Contact Email
Contact State
Contact Zip

Table2

MasterID
SubMasterID
Price
Location
Type

From the example above, After an Insert / Update into Table1, I would like to insert / update that same record into Table2, however with only the 5 columns in Table2 (meaning MasterID, SubMasterID, Price, Location, Type).

Is this actually possible with a trigger in Db2?

Or would anyone recommend writing a piece of code instead?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated.

I've tried creating a trigger (untested) like so,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCHEMA1"."TABLE1_TABLE2_INSERT" AFTER
INSERT
ON
    SCHEMA1.TABLE1 REFERENCING NEW AS A 
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT
INTO
    SCHEMA2.TABLE2
    (
        "MasterID",
        "SubMasterID",
        "Price",
        "Location",
        "Type"
    )
    VALUES
    (
        a.MasterID,
        a.SubMasterID,
        a.Price,
        a.Location,
        a.Type
            );
    END
```

However, I am unsure how this trigger can specifically identify the specific columns from Table1 to insert / update into Table2.

Comment: Namely you must provide the desired column names of both tables. Trigger doesn't have to decide this for you. This should work after a small typo correction. Have you tested this? Does it work as expected?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thank you for the typo correction. Okay, so you're saying that I can just specify the individual columns for the trigger on Table2, and that should do the trick. I will test today.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein 
I am also looking the solution for the same problem. Did you get somethings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dtc348 Ask your own new question. You should provide relevant source & target table ddl, insert statement in the base table and the result desired in the target table instead of the vague description here. It would be great, if you could provide a [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/6pjm1B_y) with all this info to start from.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks a lot for your quick feedback. I have the same scenario, but I want to trigger insert/update to another database. As per your suggestion, I will ask my own question

Comment: @MarkBarinstein please find my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74153306/db2-trigger-to-insert-update-records-into-different-database