# DB2 trigger to Insert/Update records into different database

Tags: database, triggers, db2, db2-luw

I want to create a trigger on one database's table and want to add that `records into another database's table.
Let us suppose, I have one table on first database, which has 5 rows and 2 columns. Another side I have one table on another
database, which has 3 rows and 2 columns, where 3 rows of another database's table are exact same as 3 rows of the first database's table.

I know, how to trigger the Insert/Update table on the same database. But how to trigger table from one database to another database?

Below is the code for triggering the tables in same database.

database_1 ---> schema_1 ---> table_1

```
|col1  col2|
_____|_____
|1a   1b   |
|2a   2b   |
|3a   3b   |
|4a   4b   |
|5a   5b   |
```

database_2 ---> schema_2 ---> table_2

```
|col1  col2|
_____|_____
|1a   1b   |
|2a   2b   |
|3a   3b   |
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCHEMA_1"."TRG_table_1_AFTER_UPDATE" 
    AFTER UPDATE ON "SCHEMA_1"."table_1"
    REFERENCING NEW AS new_row
    FOR EACH ROW
    NOT SECURED


Insert into SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2(col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (new_row.val1, new_row.val2, new_row.val3);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it with triggers.

The way to update tables in another database is use of nicknames.
But [CREATE TRIGGER statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-trigger) states:

> **SQL-procedure-statement**
> Specifies the SQL statement that is to be part of the triggered action. **A searched update, searched delete, insert, or merge operation
> on nicknames inside compound SQL is not supported.**

and

> A procedure that contains a reference to a nickname in a searched
> UPDATE statement, a searched DELETE statement, or an INSERT statement
> is not supported (SQLSTATE 25000).

You may use some procedural logic with, say, 2PC-enabled federated servers, but not triggers.
[Enabling two-phase commit for federated transactions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=transactions-enabling-two-phase-commit-federated)

**Update:**
You should familiarize yourself with the concept of [Federation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=federation) in Db2 firstly.
The key technical topics for Db2 -> Db2 federation are:
[Enabling the federated server to access data sources](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=server-enabling-federated-access-data-sources) (update dbm cfg parameter if needed and restart the federated server instance).
[Configuring remote Db2 data source information](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sources-configuring-remote-db2-data-source-information):

On federation server:

```
CREATE WRAPPER DRDA;

-- MYREMDB the alias of a cataloged remote database
CREATE SERVER MYSERVER
   TYPE DB2/UDB 
   VERSION '11.5' 
   WRAPPER "DRDA"
AUTHORIZATION some_user PASSWORD "some_password"
OPTIONS
(
  DBNAME  'MYREMDB'
, DB2_TWO_PHASE_COMMIT  'Y'
-- may be other options like:
, DB2_MAXIMAL_PUSHDOWN 'Y'
);

-- User mapping for some MY_LOCAL_USER
-- all work from MY_LOCAL_USER with remote tables will be with
-- this MY_REMOTE_USER account.
-- The corresponding GRANT statements must be run on
-- MY_LOCAL_USER locally and MY_REMOTE_USER remotely
-- to work with the corresponding tables
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR MY_LOCAL_USER
SERVER MYSERVER
OPTIONS
(
   REMOTE_AUTHID  'my_remote_user'
 , REMOTE_PASSWORD  'my_remote_password'
);

-- Create a nickname or use 3-part name directly in your statements
-- MYSERVER.MY_REMOTE_SCHEMA.MY_REMOTE_TABLE
CREATE NICKNAME MY_SCHEMA.MY_REMOTE_TABLE_NICKNAME
FOR MYSERVER.MY_REMOTE_SCHEMA.MY_REMOTE_TABLE;

-- Usage
-- Switch the autocommit off in your session
-- Both statements are either committed or rolled back successfully in their databases
-- because of 2PC option (DB2_TWO_PHASE_COMMIT) of the server MYSERVER
-- disregarding of what or where fails
INSERT INTO MY_LOCAL_TABLE ...;
INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.MY_REMOTE_TABLE_NICKNAME ...;
-- OR
-- INSERT INTO MYSERVER.MY_REMOTE_SCHEMA.MY_REMOTE_TABLE ...;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Really appreciating idea. I have never used "Enabling two-phase commit for federated transactions" topic. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Briefly. If you don't want inconsistent changes in your databases, you should either use 2PC transactions or some application based logic to repair possible inconsistencies. If you don't use 2PC transactions, then changes in a local and remote databases are done in different transactions, and if one of them fails, you may get unanticipated changes made by another one, which shouldn't be done in this case.

Comment: If I want to use 2PC transactions, for that, I am going through one of the documentations from Oxford University.
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2122/ConcDisSys/dist-sys-notes.pdf . I just go through the overview, 
but still I am looking for solid concept. Can 2PC transactions will solve "Insert/Update records into different database" problem? 
I will be happy, if you share concept with example with inserting/updating tables in two databases. kind regards

Comment: You should refer the official Db2 documentation where all steps are described. Look at my updated answer.